# Flink deserialize Kafka JSON

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am trying to read a json message from a kafka topic with flink.

I am using Kafka 2.4.1 and Flink 1.10

for my consumer I have set:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema;
import org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;


FlinkKafkaConsumer<ObjectNode> sensorConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer(KAFKA_TOPIC_INPUT, 
                new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false), properties);
```

when I use `SimpleStringSchema` I get the json as text which is fine but with the JSONKeyValueDeserializer I get:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'sensor_5': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
```

`sensor_5` would be a key in the topic I am guessing that I need to add something else to get the JSON from the kafka message value fed to the serializer and handle the key somehow but I am not sure?

Any suggestions?

The json structure is:

```
{"value": 1.0, "timestamp": "2020-05-01 14:00:00.000000"}
```

and it is submitted via

```
# Python 3
import json
from confluent_kafka import Producer

dict_obj = {"value": 1.0, "timestamp": "2020-05-01 14:00:00.000000"}
producer = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': "kafka:9092"})

producer.produce(topic='sensors-raw', key='sensor_5', value=json.dumps(dict_obj))
```

Comment: How the value is serialized before entering Kafka?

Comment: python3  `confluent_kafka` producer with  `json.dumps(data_dict)`. The dict is just a stock python dictionary with a mix of string and float values with different keys

Comment: Could you please post the JSON as well. So, I can reproduce the problem in my PC?

Comment: added full code to produce the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically, if You will take a look at the source code of `JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema` You can see that it looks like below :

```
    if (mapper == null) {
            mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        }
        ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode();
        if (record.key() != null) {
            node.set("key", mapper.readValue(record.key(), JsonNode.class));
        }
        if (record.value() != null) {
            node.set("value", mapper.readValue(record.value(), JsonNode.class));
        }
        if (includeMetadata) {
            node.putObject("metadata")
                .put("offset", record.offset())
                .put("topic", record.topic())
                .put("partition", record.partition());
        }
        return node;
```

So, generally the schema expects that Your key is JSON not a String, thus it will fail for `sensor_5`.  I think the best and simplest solution would be to create Your own implementation that takes String as key.

Comment: so does that mean I have to use `org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.KafkaDeserializationSchema` create my own class of that then use `JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema` as the deserialization schema in the `deserialize` method of that so that the Kafka key is handled and the json message is handled as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `DeserializationSchema` instead of `KeyedDeserializationSchema` if you don't want to include your key in your record.

An example would be like the following:

```
public class JSONValueDeserializationSchema implements DeserializationSchema<ObjectNode> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public ObjectNode deserialize(byte[] message) throws IOException {
        if (mapper == null) {
            mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        }
        ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode();
        if (message != null) {
            node.set("value", mapper.readValue(message, JsonNode.class));
        }
        return node;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(ObjectNode nextElement) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<ObjectNode> getProducedType() {
        return getForClass(ObjectNode.class);
    }
}
```

If you want to include the key as well in your record, you can implement `KeyedDeserializationSchema` as mentioned in the answer by Dominik Wosiński.