# How to read JSON Messages from Kafka Topic using Apache Flink in Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am trying to read JSON Messages from Kafka topic using Apache Flink and Scala. This is an example of one massege:

```
{"brand": "apple", "category": "phone", "productid": "2", "productname":"iphone"}
```

My code is like that:

```
object ProductModel extends Serializable {

  def readElement(jsonElement: JsValue): productJs= {
      val brand = (jsonElement \ "brand").as[String]
      val category = (jsonElement \ "category").as[String]
      val productid = (jsonElement \ "productid").as[String]
      val productname = (jsonElement \ "productname").as[String]
      productJs(brand, category, productid, productname)
  }

  case class productJs(brand: String, category: String, productid: String, productname: String)

}

val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

val properties = new Properties()
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
properties.setProperty("group.id", "flink-consumer-group")
properties.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")

val consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("my-topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)
val stream1 = env.addSource(consumer)

val stream2 = stream1.map{ x => ProductModel.readElement(Json.parse(x))}

stream2.print()

env.execute("FlinkKafkaScala")
```

However, I am getting the following error:
org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: Task not serializable

Can anyone please correct and explain my erros? The code must be in Scala. Thank you in advance

Comment: The data you've shared is not valid JSON. Keys must be quoted. All string values must be quoted. And why do you need a case class inside of another class / object?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I've corrected the formatting of the JSON; it was written like that by mistake. I am asking how to parse the josn format using Flink in Scala, My code has incorrect parts as well.

Comment: Your readElement function seems fine. I think it's the case class that cannot be serialized. But instead, you should use a deserialization schema class https://stackoverflow.com/q/61561703/2308683